# Combining two snap svg groups into one single group

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom, snap.svg

I have two snap svg groups `grp1` and `grp2`. Now I want to combine these two groups to become one group. I have tried `append()`, `appendTo()`, `prepend()`, `prependTo()` but all of them add one group inside another in one way or the other.

Here is [code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapil_sarwat/ghx46zqu/16/)

Does anybody have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SnapSVG, you are **not** working with Nodes

That means your `g1` and `g2` are Snap *Objects*

To use DOM methods like `append`, you need to dig a little deeper to access the Nodes

- Documentation: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.node

The advantage of SnapSVG is you can **chain** methods

**Working code:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id="Canvas" height="100"></svg>


<script>
let canvas = Snap('#Canvas');

let g1 = canvas.g()
               .add(canvas.rect(10, 10, 80, 60).attr({fill: 'green'}))
               .add(canvas.circle(150, 60, 40 ).attr({fill: 'gold'}));
let g2 = canvas.g()
               .add(canvas.circle(150, 60, 20 ).attr({fill: 'red'}));

g1.node.append(...g2.node.children);
g2.remove();

document.body.append(canvas.node.innerHTML)
</script>
```